# RxJava2 using retryWhen with filter

Tags: java, android, rx-java2, retrywhen

I've been playing around with **retryWhen()** method and i noticed that if you use **filter()** inside **retryWhen()** and if **filter()** fails there's no callback executed not even **onCompleted()**. Can you please explain to me why is this happening? Thanks in advance.

The working case:

```
    Observable.error(new RuntimeException())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .retryWhen(errors -> errors
                    .filter(throwable -> throwable instanceof RuntimeException)
                    .zipWith(Observable.range(1, 3), (throwable, retryCount) -> {
                        Log.i("lol", "retry " + retryCount);
                        return retryCount;
                    }))
            .subscribe(e -> Log.i("lol", "onNext"), throwable -> Log.i("lol", "onError"), () -> Log.i("lol", "onCompleted"));
```

The working output:

```
I: retry 1
I: retry 2
I: retry 3
I: onCompleted
```

But when i changed the filter with `filter(throwable -> throwable instanceof IOException)` the observable is like in a frozen state. No callback fired.

```
Observable.error(new RuntimeException())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .retryWhen(errors -> errors
                        .filter(throwable -> throwable instanceof IOException)
                        .zipWith(Observable.range(1, 3), (throwable, retryCount) -> {
                            Log.i("lol", "retry " + retryCount);
                            return retryCount;
                        }))
                .subscribe(e -> Log.i("lol", "onNext"), throwable -> Log.i("lol", "onError"), () -> Log.i("lol", "onCompleted"));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't want to use `filter()` inside the `retryWhen()` operator. Instead, use an `if` statement or `switch` statement to ensure you have complete coverage of all cases.

The way that `retryWhen()` works is that it creates an observable and invoking the function with it. When it catches the throwable in its `onError()` method, it emits that throwable into the observable and waits for the result. If it gets no result, such as when a throwable is filtered, it will wait forever.

Comment: Thanks for the info.Yeah I was using `if` statement but just wanted to try if it works with `filter()` too. Though I'd expect at least `onCompleted()` method called in this case.

Comment: Again, since the operator does not hear anything back, it won't do anything. The observable supplied to your function will not complete unless the source completes.